# Abrir un Dialog() desde un archivo .JS usando un DropDownList

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Hola soy nuevo programando y quisiera saber si se puede tener un Dropdown list de asp que se abra dependiendo de la seleccion, un dialog() de jquery pero que este dialog() ste dentro de un archivo comun .js

tengo un script que al colocarlo directo en la pagina abre sin problemas pero quiero usar el mismo y hacerlo "Comun" dentro de un .JS y que me abra dentro de otra pagina del mismo proyecto.

es posible?

y si se puede, necesito un ejemplo para hacerlo.

Comment: hola utiliza la accion del control [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056508/onchange-event-for-html-dropdownlist/25056654#25056654](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056508/onchange-event-for-html-dropdownlist/25056654#25056654)

Comment: ok probare y les comento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con javascript jquery

```
@Html.DropDownList("Sortby", new SelectListItem[] 
 { new SelectListItem() { Text = "Newest to Oldest", Value = "0" }, 
   new SelectListItem() { Text = "Oldest to Newest", Value = "1" }},
   new { @onchange="CallChangefunc(this.value)" })

<script>
function CallChangefunc(val)
{
 $( "#dialog" ).dialog();;
}
 </script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

la fuente esta en el comentario que escribí

Comment: gracias probare y les comento.

Comment: @KyuwanLightskater si esta respuesta solucionó el problema expuesto en la pregunta, deberías marcarla como aceptada.